# Native input awaiting in multithreading c++ windows

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm writing a C++ game interactor. It's job is to compile and run user-sent code and exchange information with it. Interactions looks something like: interactor sends a map to a bot. Bot reads the map using std::cin and then prints his move using std::cout. The problem is that I can't find out how to make user's bot not to read some trash out of std::cin stream because of bad thread order. I can imagine how to do this using ifstream::peek, eof, e.t.c, but I don't want the user to face streams sync order problems. So I want user to be able to simply write an std::cin, std::cout in his code while being able to receive all the input in time.

That's the basic template of what the programs should do. I tried to somehow make overloaded stdin and stdout to wait for input to be entered, but I couldn't do so.

main code:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h> // just an example :P

void runOtherFile() {
    system("g++ -o test.exe test.cpp");
    system("test.exe <input.txt >output.txt");
}

signed main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::thread thread(runOtherFile);
    std::cout << 123; 
    std::cout.flush();
    thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

test.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    int a;
    std::cin >> a; // here we need to have a to be already stored in the input file
    std::cout << a << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why not just avoid spawning a thread at all? You could just run all of your code directly inside main() instead.

Comment: As I said, I want to be able to receive user's code in an executable or a cpp file and perform an interaction within a game handler and a player's bot. I could paste possible user's code in main, but that would be awful :) And that won't work with an executable as well

Comment: tbh c++ has no utility for IPC out of the box, so my best suggestion is to use [boost.Process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/process.html), it will make the whole process 10 times easier.

Comment: a better idea would be to write this in python, as its standard library alone can run like a hundred of them in parallel out of the box, and that's what people use python for anyway.

Comment: thank you, i'll consider using boost. i don't want to use python because of personal interest of writing this in c/cpp.

Comment: @systy257 I think you misunderstood my comment.  I wasn't saying you should paste the user's code into main(), only that you can get rid of the `std::thread` stuff and just call `runOtherFile()` directly from main() instead.

Comment: Oh, ok. But that still doesn't look a solution for me as I need to have users' bots make continuous moves. So they should be able to read information and then give it back many times during the runtime.

Comment: I see no need to use multiple threads for this. Using the Windows API, you can call [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) with `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` set in the `STARTUPINFO` structure. The function [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) can be used to wait for the created process to finish and also to wait for new input or output to be available. You won't be able to use C++ streams, though.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to implement this using win api tomorrow, if it does actually solve the problem. But would be still very interesting to find the answer the question. I have probably seen this problem solved on practice in ejudge and interactive CP problems, but that could be some sort of modification with no source code available.

Comment: See also libuv instead of faffing around with the windows APIs.